# Discriminator verification command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discriminator command w/ d.py. Basically, you enter a message, and if that matches your discriminator, a role is added. I have used the `print()` strategy on parts of the code, and this part is causing the problem. (No error, though)

```
    if message.channel == channel:
        print(message.content)
        if message.author.discriminator in message.content:
            await message.author.send(f'You are now verified in **{message.guild}**.')
            await message.delete()
            return await message.author.add_roles(role, atomic=True)
        else:
            return await message.delete()
    else:
        return
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Can you please elaborate on the expected vs. the current behaviour?

Comment: Is `role` defined? If so, where is it defined and how?

Comment: role = discord.utils.get(
            message.guild.roles, name="Verified")